# How to reverse the display of the messages of a folder? (to force that the last messsages apppear at top instead of bottom)

Tags: email-client, sylpheed

I like Sylpheed email client because it is very light and fast.

But I have a small problem with it:

When I am viewing some folder (Inbox, Sent, or other folders) the last unseen messages or last messages (if there is no new message) are shown at the bottom.

I would like that last message appear at the top for **all folders**. I mean, I would prefer the dafault display be reversed. Like the gmail interface in which last message appear at the top for all folders.

I didn't find an option to achieve this in Sylpheed.

Many email client (like Thunderbird) are able to show the last message at the top of the dialogue for all folders. I would like to the same thing with Sylpheed.

Comment: You cannot click on the header of the date column to invert the sort order?

Comment: @vanadium Unfortunately when there are many many messages in a folder, any type of sorting slows down the openning of the folder. I prefer to keep "Don't Sort" option in "View>Sort" menu. I just like with the default option "Don't Sort" the direction of the index of the folder be reversed.

Comment: @vanadium Other inconvenience of sort by date column is that I should do it for all folders manually which is time consuming when there is too many folders.

Comment: **"Don't Sort"** is the fastest way to access folders in email clients.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by the `Number` column instead of `Date` column.

The Number column is not visible by default. You have to enable it.

Click on your current Mailbox (or the folders individually) then click on `View > Set Display item ...`.

Then add `Number` from `Available items` to `Displayed items`.

This will add `Number` column to each folders (some folder like `Sent` may possibly need the above action separately, that is, you should click on them and do the above procedure).

Then Click on the `Number` column to reverse the ordering.

This is faster than reversing the `Date` column.